# al.exe parameter too long

Tags: localization, al.exe

I am trying to create localized satellite assemblies for a product i'm working on. I'm using the resgen.exe tool to compile the .resx files in my project into .resource files.

I then use the following command to embed the resource file into a new assembly.

`al.exe /t:lib /out:"C:\Localisation\Translations\dll_files\PBS.POS.UI.Common\es\PBS.POS.UI.Common.resources.dll" /culture:es /embed:"C:\Localisation\Translations\resource_files\PBS.POS.UI.Common\es\ARPaymentMethodLookup.es.resources",POS.POS.UI.Common.ARPaymentMethodLookup.es.resources`

The /embed: parameter is repeated for each resource file.

One of my projects has a very large number of forms and therefore a large number of .resx and .resource files (one for each form). This results in the /embed: parameter being repeated enough times that the command it hits the 8000 character limit in the console. I'm therefor unable to generate the assembly.

The product is quite small and I imagine that other applications on the market have gotten around this issue somehow. Ideally i'd like to avoid having to go back over all the forms in the project and move the localised strings into a single file as this will be a very time consuming process.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`al.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx) will take a response file.

Put the parameters, one per line or space separated, into a text file, then call:

```
al @filename
```